# Android pass keyEvent to next subsequent view

Tags: java, android

I have a custom view added to the `WindowManager`, set the `focusInTouchMode` to true and requested focus for it so that I can listen for `onKeyDown().

I just need the KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP and VOLUNE_DOWN keys and return false for anything else. But the problem is that the KEYCODE_BACK is never passed through my view and activities don't receive it so they don't handle the back button. Is there any way to handle this?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP ||
            keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {

        // Handling the event
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        this.setFocusable(false);
        this.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        this.clearFocus();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: WHy did you add a custom view for that, rather than set a listener on the root view?

Comment: @GabeSechan well I already have a custom view added and I wanted to reuse it for this purpose as well. And would it change anything if the `onKeyDown` was set on the root view?

Comment: Yes, you'd be part of the normal key event chain.  Adding anything to the window manager is actually a very unusual act-  the only time I've ever done it is to display a dialog directly from a service.  Its almost always the wrong thing to do.  Of course it'd be easier to see if you're just doing something else weird if you posted your code.

Comment: @GabeSechan just edited it. Also I need to listen for the volume keys in the background (I have a service attached as well) and be indpendent of my app's Activities.

Comment: So the back button shouldn't be received by this function at all, but it goes to a separate activity level onBackButtonPressed.  Is that firing properly, or is it unresposnive?

Comment: @GabeSechan It first fires correctly and removes focus from my view. But afterwords it doesn't dispatch the event to the activity. Plus the logging inside my `onKeyDown` doesn't get called either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135113/discussion-between-alex-newman-and-gabe-sechan).